# is it acceptable to recycle or reuse variables?

Tags: php, oop, variables, methods, dependency-injection

I've looked everywhere, and I can't seem to find an answer one way or another. Is it acceptable (good or bad practice) to reuse or recycle a variable? It works, and I've used this method a few times, but I don't know if I should be doing this or not. I'm trying to get away from using static methods, and moving into dependency injection.

in this example, the $table_name is set elsewhere.

```
class DbObject {
    private $db = NULL;
    protected $table_name;

    public function __construct($dbh, $item) {
        $this->db = $dbh;
        $this->$table_name = $item;
    }

    // counts items in database //
    public function count_all() {
        try {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $this->table_name;

            $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
            $stmt->setFetchMode(pdo::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
            $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

To use this I would use it like this:

```
$total_count = new DbObject(new Database(), 'items');
$total_count = $total_count->count_all();
```

Is this an acceptable way to code? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is technically correct, but it will lead to a lot of confusion during debugging

Comment: The question is somewhat misworded: Variables are often re-used and "recycled" (that's what they are for, you often use a variable more than once). You are more concerned about the variable name. Which actually answers the question: Don't use the same name for different things if you don't wanna have false friends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reusing variables for different purposes is a maintenance error waiting to happen.

It's bad practice. A well named variable can do wonders for aiding code comprehension.

Reusing variables is especially fragile in weakly typed dynamic languages such as PHP.

[In the past, I have been guilty of errors in code when reusing local loop variables like `i` and `j` ...]

Comment: Thanks. It works, which is why i've gone with it in the past, but seemed like it would be considered bad practice, which is why i figured i should probably ask around.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason to avoid reusing variables is that if you reuse a variable without properly re-initializing it, the old value will "leak" through, causing unpredictable effects and even security vulnerabilities. For example:

```
$foo = $_GET['input'];
# use $foo

if ($a == $b) {
    $foo = 1;
} else {
    # $foo = 2; # Commented out for some reason
}
# Value $foo supplied in URL leaks through to here
```

Generally, reuse of variables will not damage performance if the compiler uses single-static assignment form (SSA) as an intermediate form during optimization (part of what SSA does is giving separate names to such reused variables). So don't worry about performance - worry about maintainability.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i never really thought of it that way.

Comment: If the old variable was a reference, even more bad things can happen

Answer (score 2):

What about when you need call another method of the `DbObject` ?

I prefer give the variable name what it is:

```
$dbo = new DbObject(new Database(), 'items');
$total_count = $dbo->count_all();

//so you call still do things next
$result = $dbo->get_all();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like using common names often through out a script (e.g. `$i` for counting iterations in a loop) you should have no problems if you make it a habit to call `unset()` whenever you're done with using a variable in a particular case.

Answer (score 0):

People tend to re-use "throw-away" variables like *i* and *j*, but it is usually bad form to reuse other local variables for a different purpose.  That leads to reader confusion about where a variable is initialized and whether updates in one part of the code will affect another part of the code.  There may also be ill-effects on a compiler's optimization suite (perhaps suggesting a variable should be saved when it isn't necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the variables could conflict or you could get them mixed out. So I would only reuse `$i` and `$row` unless you `unset()` the variable when you are done.