# Using same variable again in PDO queries

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO prepared statement. Here in the code i use variable `res` for first prepare statement & operations.

```
$res=$db->prepare("//code//");
$res->execute($array);
$count=$res->rowCount();

$res=$db->prepare("//code//");
$res->execute($array);
$res->fetch();
```

Will it create problems if i use reuse the variable for another prepared statement? Is it a wrong practice and should i use another variable for other statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're done with that variable, I think you can safely reuse it (I would do it), but some code conventions try to avoid this kind of behaviour.

See for example this other question: [is it acceptable to recycle or reuse variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089961/is-it-acceptable-to-recycle-or-reuse-variables)